# Extracting fit weights directly from a FittedModel object

Tags: fitting

Suppose I have the following data:

```
data = {{{4.05, -5.06579}, ErrorBar[0.180393]},
        {{ 4.1, -4.93148}, ErrorBar[0.191881]},
        {{4.15, -5.14983}, ErrorBar[0.201101]}}
```

and I fit it to a constant with weights that are 1/the error bar as follows:

```
fit = LinearModelFit[ data[[All,1]], 1, t, Weights -> 1/( Sequence@@@data[[All,2]] )^2 ]
```

Then I know I can recover the actual data points via `fit["Data"]`. Is it possible to recover the weights used in the fit? I have searched through the documentation extensively and none of the options of `FittedModel` seem to produce what I'm looking for (and the weights don't seem to be stored in the same way when I look at `FullForm@fit`).

I'd like to accomplish this because then my analysis can be independent of the data set -- I could just pass around the `FittedModel` output objects themselves.

Comment: I'm confused. Since you seem to be providing the fitting function with explicit values for the weights that you calculate from `data`, can't you just recalculate the weights in the same way?

Comment: This is an extremely simplified example.  In reality, I have many many data sets, and life would be tremendously simplified if I didn't have to keep track of which fit came from which set.  That is, I'd love to generate the fits and then be able to (in principle) throw away `data`.

Comment: I see. Well, interesting question, and we learned something from Belisarius' answer! If you haven't seen it already, you might also be interested in the following tutorial on using `Weights` together with `VarianceEstimatorFunction` : [How to | Fit Models with Measurement Errors](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/FitModelsWithMeasurementErrors.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The weights are there, but not documented.
Please beware that the following may not work in future releases. I tested it on v9.

```
data = {{{4.05, -5.06579}, ErrorBar[0.180393]}, {{4.1, -4.93148}, ErrorBar[0.191881]},
        {{4.15, -5.14983}, ErrorBar[0.201101]}};
w    =  1/data[[All, 2, 1]]^2;
fit  = LinearModelFit[data[[All, 1]], 1, t, Weights -> w];
fit[[2, 1]] == w

(* True *)
```

---

Note that `NonlinearModelFit` has a different internal structure:

```
nlFit = NonlinearModelFit[data[[All, 1]], 1, {t}, Weights -> w];
nlFit[[4]] 
(*
 Weights -> {30.7299, 27.1604, 24.727}
*)
```

Comment: (+1) `w = 1/(Sequence @@@ data[[All, 2]])^2` can be simplified to `w = 1/data[[All, 2, 1]]^2`.

Comment: Works in v10, too!  Thanks!

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks. Editing :)

Comment: @belisarius There may be differences between your version and v. 10.2 that I am using. In my version, the `NonlinearModelFit` expression you use doesn't work. Something like `NonlinearModelFit[data[[All, 1]], a, a, t, Weights -> w]` will work instead. Also, in my version `nlFit[[4]]` returns something abstruse; the Weights can be retrieved with `nlFit[[2,1]]` just like in the `LinearModelFit` result.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks! I don't have a Mma v10 installed to test it :(  A pity